# How to apply a HttpUtility decoder

Tags: c#

First time I've had to use a `HttpUtility` decoder. Do I place the `HttpUtility` at the end of this piece of code (below)? Or do I create a new method and run the string through it? One other caveat the code below refers to a class name `Utils`, where there is some XML parsing going on. If the solution is to create a new method would it be correct to place the `HttpUtility` after the XML parsing?

At the end of the XML parsing the method hands off the parsing to links "return links". Would I then need to hand off the parsing to the `HttpUtility`, and at the end of the `HttpUtility` hand the result off to links? `Utils.CS` is pasted below the web client code.

Sorry for the lengthy question, I've only been coding for about 8 months and haven't come across every scenario.

```
 public void LoadFeed()
 {
        //check if network and client are available
        if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(uri))
        {
            LoadingState = LoadingState.LOADING;
            RaisePropertyChanged("LoadingState");
            var wc = new WebClient();
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>

            {
                if (e.Error == null)
                {
                    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        LoadingState = LoadingState.COMPLETED;
                        FeedLinks = Utils.GetLinksFromFeed(e.Result);
                        RaisePropertyChanged("FeedLinks");
                        RaisePropertyChanged("LoadingState");
                    });
                }
            };
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Absolute));
        }
        else
        {
            LoadingState = LoadingState.ERROR;
            RaisePropertyChanged("LoadingState");
        }
```

`Utils.CS`:

```
public static List<Link> GetLinksFromFeed(string xmlString)
{
        List<Link> links = null;

        //try to parse result as rss feed
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
        //grab default namespace
        XNamespace xName = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
        //parse items
        links = (from item in doc.Descendants(xName + "item")
                 select new Link
                 {
                     Title = item.Element(xName + "title").Value,
                     Url = item.Element(xName + "link").Value,
                 }).ToList<Link>();

        return links;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can modify Utils.cs, you could wrap the Title and Url assignments with HttpUtility.HtmlDecode

```
...
select new Link
{
    Title = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.Element(xName + "title").Value),
    Url = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.Element(xName + "link").Value),
}).ToList<Link>();
...
```

or you can wrap e.Result with it in your LoadFeed method

```
...
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    LoadingState = LoadingState.COMPLETED;
    FeedLinks = Utils.GetLinksFromFeed(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e.Result));
    RaisePropertyChanged("FeedLinks");
    RaisePropertyChanged("LoadingState");
});
```

Comment: That worked beautifully. Much...Much...Much appreciated. I added the wrapper to the Utils.cs class and all is well.